# LIKE Column query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

It is easy to do a `Contains`, `StartsWith`, or `EndsWith` query in Entity Framework when you know the pattern you'd like to find.  But how to do the equivalent of "LIKE [Column]"?

For instance, this is easy:

```
Name LIKE '%Th'
```

But how do you do this?  where Prefix is a column.

```
Name LIKE [Prefix]
```

I tried to use the `SqlMethods` and got the following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this. When you write the query, just determine yourself when to use Contains (equivalent to `LIKE '%...%'`) or StartsWith (equivalent to `LIKE '...%'`) or EndsWidth (equivalent to `LIKE '%...'`) easily .

Comment: This is a situation in which patterns are actually stored in certain columns.  So I need the to be able to evaluate Like [Column] in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using LINQ to Entities to bring back the set of data that I wanted, then using LINQ to Objects to filter the data.

I do not think there is currently a way to have a LINQ to Entities query be resolved in a database server as ...

```
... LIKE [column-name]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [SqlMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for use in LINQ-to-SQL, not LINQ-to-Entities.

The best you can do to use the filter in the database engine (so you don't have to pull all data in memory first) is:

```
context.Entities.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM EntityTable WHERE Name LIKE Prefix")
```